# How to do port address translation to connect to a reverse port forward locally

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding, nat, sles

I'm running 4 splunk indexers and I have to connect to it on port 9997.  I have no direct line of sight or any way of routing to these splunk servers other than reverse ssh portforwards which I can connect to on 127.0.0.1:8971, 127.0.0.1:8972, 127.0.0.1:8973 and 127.0.0.1:8974.

How can I trick my linux machine (sles 11 SP4) into thinking:

- 1.2.3.1:9997 -> 127.0.0.1:8971
- 1.2.3.2:9997 -> 127.0.0.1:8972
- 1.2.3.3:9997 -> 127.0.0.1:8973
- 1.2.3.4:9997 -> 127.0.0.1:8974

I've got an output rule

```
   51  3060 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            1.2.3.4       tcp dpt:9997 to:127.0.0.1:8971
```

which works, but the response I get is garbage

```
14:37:23.425219 IP 192.168.58.10.55403 > 127.0.0.1.8971: S 2063729062:2063729062(0) win 14600 <mss 1460,sackOK,timestamp 1532158690 0,nop,wscale 5>
14:37:23.425243 IP 127.0.0.1.8971 > 192.168.58.10.55403: S 2663988489:2663988489(0) ack 2063729063 win 32768 <mss 16396,sackOK,timestamp        1532158690 1532158690,nop,wscale 5> 
14:37:23.425249 IP 192.168.58.10.55403 > 127.0.0.1.8971: R 2063729063:2063729063(0) win 0
```

and doesn't complete the socket the way it would if I connected straight to the port forward

```
14:38:33.822640 IP 127.0.0.1.34731 > 127.0.0.1.8971: S 2794569169:2794569169(0) win 32792 <mss 16396,sackOK,timestamp 1532176289 0,nop,wscale 5>
14:38:33.822649 IP 127.0.0.1.8971 > 127.0.0.1.34731: S 1241947612:1241947612(0) ack 2794569170 win 32768 <mss 16396,sackOK,timestamp 1532176289 1532176289,nop,wscale 5>
14:38:33.822655 IP 127.0.0.1.34731 > 127.0.0.1.8971: . ack 1 win 1025 <nop,nop,timestamp 1532176289 1532176289>
14:38:33.822991 IP 127.0.0.1.34731 > 127.0.0.1.8971: F 1:1(0) ack 1 win 1025 <nop,nop,timestamp 1532176289 1532176289>
14:38:33.825172 IP 127.0.0.1.8971 > 127.0.0.1.34731: . ack 2 win 1024 <nop,nop,timestamp 1532176290 1532176289>
14:38:33.835115 IP 127.0.0.1.8971 > 127.0.0.1.34731: F 1:1(0) ack 2 win 1024 <nop,nop,timestamp 1532176292 1532176289>
14:38:33.835138 IP 127.0.0.1.34731 > 127.0.0.1.8971: . ack 2 win 1025 <nop,nop,timestamp 1532176292 1532176292>
```

Comment: Is is possible to use dns names instead of ip addresses?

Comment: @John negatory, I'm in a tiny subnet on a server that is only accessible via SSH. But I would like to know how using dns names might help.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use dns or host names, it would be possible to do the following

1. open the ssh with reverse tunneling (best to use a keyed ssh connection for system automation)
2. after the tunnel is established, add the host name entries to the /etc/hosts file but point them at 127.0.0.1
3. when the tunnel goes down, remove those entries from the /etc/hosts file.

Step 1 is pretty straight forward, lots of examples are available.
Step 2 and 3 are not as straight forward, but are easy enough

At a high level, use a cron triggered script, look at the output from netstat to determine if you have active reverse connections and then re-write your host file with sed or awk to point to the proper address.

If host names aren't really workable, it might be possible to re-define your remote tunnel setup to use 127.0.0.x rather than 1 and spread your ports around.

something like

```
ssh credentials -NT -R 1.2.3.1:9997:127.0.0.2:9997
```

Comment: Heh, I think this was what I was going to do initially (I was going to do it by IP, but hostnames might be useful). But you mean using tunnel interfaces, right?   I probably will go back to this method if I can't get any more traction here.

Comment: My answer saved before I was finished.  Based on your comment, the second option might work better.

Comment: That doesn't work because of `debug1: Remote: Forwarding listen address "127.0.0.2" overridden by server GatewayPorts` thinking there's a reason on these machines I can't change that...

Comment: Check the remote server's /etc/ssh/sshd_config for the state that AllowTcpForwarding is in.  It may be necessary to create a per-user override section for the connection user and allow it.